# Qt 4.8 on Linux - Previewer example not working for https url

Tags: c++, qt, webview, webkit, qt4

*Previewer* in *examples/webkit* folder in Qt 4.8 on Linux not showing pages that begins with 'https'.

I am using OpenSSL 1.0.1 installed in location /usr/local/ssl. The same example working fine on Windows machine.

This is just strange. What to do to show https pages??

Comment: Are openssl libraries linked in the pro file?

Comment: yes..im linking libcrypto.a and libssl.a in .pro file alongwith path to opnssl include